# Select #levels and tile size for making pyramid using gdal_retile for geoserver

Tags: geoserver, gdal

I am looking at the tutorial for building tiles for use in geoserver. https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html
The example for building a pyramid is:

```
mkdir bmpyramid
gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -targetDir bmpyramid bmreduced.tiff
```

I wonder how to decide/rule of thumb on how many levels to select and its implications and what to consider selecting tile size? In my case its an orthophoto with a total size of 250GB (split into 8000 files).

-levels 4: the number of levels in the pyramid
-ps 2048 2048: each tile in the pyramid will be a 2048x2048 GeoTIFF

Are there any general guidelines to make a good decisions?

Comment: try not to open more than a few 100 files at any one level

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Will have that in mind.